# Lifetime may not live long enough returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am trying to implement sort of a curry function that takes in an initial `&str`, and returns a function that check if a another string matches that starting from some index. which would look like this in js.

```js
const str = s => (targetString, index) => {
    if (targetString.slice(index).startsWith(s)) {
        return {
            result: s,
            index: index + s.length
        }
    }

    throw new Error("Could not match")
}
```

My Rust attempt

```rust
struct ParseError {}

struct ParseResult<'a> {
    result: Result<&'a str, ParseError>,
    index: usize
}

pub fn str<'a>(s: &'a str) -> impl Fn(&str, usize) -> ParseResult {
    let cloned = s.clone();
    let string_parse = move |target_string: &str, index: usize| -> ParseResult {
        if target_string[index..].starts_with(cloned) {
            return ParseResult {
                result: Ok(cloned.clone()),
                index: index + cloned.len()
            }
        }
        return ParseResult { result: Err(ParseError {}), index: index + cloned.len() }
    };
    return string_parse
}
```

```rust
lifetime may not live long enough
returning this value requires that `'a` must outlive `'static`rustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
main.rs(10, 12): lifetime `'a` defined here
main.rs(10, 66): to declare that `impl for<'a> Fn(&'a str, usize) -> for<'a> ParseResult<'a>` captures data from argument `s`, you can add an explicit `'a` lifetime bound: ` + 'a`
```

Comment: This question happens to have enough information, but in the future, click "Click for full compiler diagnostic" and copy that text. The inline errors are brief messages that don't give full information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you tell the return type of your `str` function that it has the explicit lifetime `'a` it works just fine:

```rust
struct ParseError {}

struct ParseResult<'a> {
    result: Result<&'a str, ParseError>,
    index: usize
}

pub fn str<'a>(s: &'a str) -> impl Fn(&str, usize) -> ParseResult<'a> {
    let string_parse = move |target_string: &str, index: usize| -> ParseResult {
        if target_string[index..].starts_with(s) {
            return ParseResult {
                result: Ok(s.clone()),
                index: index + s.len()
            }
        }
        return ParseResult { result: Err(ParseError {}), index: index + s.len() }
    };
    return string_parse
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=42a025063c7119aca0bdfa2b1e7c5421)

I also removed your `cloned` value which was unnecessary and I assume you only added for debugging purposes to begin with.

Comment: I thought i need to clone the string just so I can have a copy that is in the inner scope so then this function wouldnt take ownership.